# Why my table is not using Index?

Tags: mysql, database

I cant see my table is using Index...EXPLAIN given me this

```
id select_type  table      type  possible_keys  key key_len  ref   rows Extra
1  SIMPLE           table1     const  web       web  258     const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table2     const  web       web  258     const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table3     const  web       web  258     const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table4     const  web       web  258     const  1
```

Comment: If you could supply the table definition, that'd be helpful.

Comment: `key` and `index` are the same. What is your question? I explained in reasonable detail the output of your `EXPLAIN` statement in an [answer to one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138559/can-you-tell-what-is-wrong-with-this-query).

Comment: oh sorry extra wasn't showing "using index" message hence I thought it isn't utilizing index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using the index called `web`. Key means index.

```
id select_type      table      type   possible_keys  key  key_len  ref    rows Extra
1  SIMPLE           table1     const  web            web  258      const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table2     const  web            web  258      const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table3     const  web            web  258      const  1    
1  SIMPLE           table4     const  web            web  258      const  1
                                                     ^^^
```