# Should validation of unique fields be handled on database level?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, validation

I am writing quite a large web application for my BSc project and am writing it in PHP using MySQL.

When creating the SQL tables should I use unique fields? The reason I ask this is because I am writing validation methods into my PHP. For example, if I wanted to check if an email address already exists in the database I would first make an SQL statement seeing if any email addresses are returned and then insert the initial SQL data into the database.

If I was to just insert the initial SQL data it would throw an error on the entire statement because email addresses must be unique.

Is this the correct way of approaching validation?

Comment: one option is to make it unique, then trap the error on insert and that will tell you it s a duplicate, this saves adding a select and an insert - eliminates one db querry

Comment: In joinery - you would never leave a mortise and tenon join unglued. You define columns as unique to maintain data integrity. Thinking that the application layer will keep things consistent is one of the worse mistakes you can make.

Never neglect your data integrity.

Comment: You mentioned MySQL. Maybe you cant consider PostgreSQL instead of MySQL. We use PostgreSQL for many years in web development (Apache+PHP+PostgreSQL) because its capabilities of server side programming and data consistency. I'm sure PostgreSQL best option (if you are not fixed to MySQL).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well...these are two entirely different things. By setting contraints (like unique) on columns in the database you can prevent a wrong dataset to be inserted into the database. That's basic stuff to ensure data consistency. By adding validation to your application you add another layer. While preventing that wrong datasets will be inserted into the database, you mainly create means to tell the user what he did wrong.

You need both of those. And in general unique constraints should not be the only things taking care of your database. It's recommended to also use foreign key constraints and if applicable more complex data validations as well (custom constraints). However, as you are using MySQL not a lot of that is really available to you

Just go for as much as you can get, because in the end it will prevent a lot of headaches trying to figure out why a particular error occurred until you finally realize that the data in your database is wrong. That can really be a pain.

Comment: Thanks. This answer makes a lot of sense to me. Explaining to the user is that an entry has not been added is one of the main reasons I asked the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend that approach, because **only the database constrains can guarantee you uniqueness**.

If there are 2 requests running parallelly, both can accept the same e-mail address, and you have 2 users with the same email address.

Also, probably you will do a search filtering on the database, so in MySQL you want to have an index on the email. So, then there's not much difference making that column unique.

Answer (score 1):

Validation should be performed client side (javascript for example) because it generally gives a better user experience.  It should be used serverside becuase client side can be bypassed.  And should be enforced on the database because any constraint that is not enforced on the database, is not a constraint... it's only a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, database should check if data are correct. Database holds data regardless how they got there. Sometime maybe you will work with the database from another application and this aplication needs to validate data too. It is more secure to check whether data are correct both in an application (frontend and backend) and at database level.

Answer (score 0):

Often, it is a case of working out where the code *should* be. This is an example of [Dijkstra's "Separation of Concerns"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Given that making the fields Unique means that you:

`Don't need to write validation code, ergo ultimately you write less code`

`The validation for values in the database, is in a logical place; bound to the database!`

This is a question of data modelling. Simply ask yourself the question "Where does it make sense for this code to be?". In my opinion, using the Unique value in the database is the right way to go. It abstracts the validation away from your PHP code, and means you can alter it without having to change any of your core model logic.

Answer (score 0):

Creating **UNIQUE** constraints on the field for email addresses is the best approach because of it's high selectivity, but be sure you also set the field to **NOT NULL**,

I find that using the constraints would be a whole lot better, but you can also do in via a query,  like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE email = '$email'
```

More on the subject: [mysql 5.0 indexes - Unique vs Non Unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388982/mysql-5-0-indexes-unique-vs-non-unique)

Comment: UNIQUE constraint is not good solution in this case. What do you do when you delete this account but a) you need to keep history records connected to this account and b) you want to allow do a new registration with this e-mail address?

Comment: Nice, its true, although you can update the database like an index on a hard drive and append a -disabled symbol freeing the username's availability but keeping the record for backup. But in the context, an email should only belong to one person, (high selectivity)

Answer (score -2):

And then one day you decide to switch from MySQL to some other database and all of your "validation" no longer exists (switching to a database like MongoDB for example).

Please do not do this - do it at the application level. It's simple, version controlled, testable etc.

By all means - create your unique index in MySQL, but I wouldn't rely on that alone.