# VB.net Database User Validation

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net

**REAL PROBLEM:** I am making a admin control panel for my mysql database. I just learned the most of the stuff in vb.net i know everything now learning query language and i run into this question. I want that there would be a user validator(detector) what i mean is lets say someone is creating an account and the username exist it would show a messagebox that the username already exist and cancel creating the account.

Here is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Deathlairregnu
    Dim MySqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim MySqlCmd As MySqlCommand
    Private Sub ButtonNUS_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNUS.Click
        MySqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MySqlConn.ConnectionString =
            "server=localhost;userid=root;password=CONSORED;database=syscore"
        Dim MySqlRea As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            MySqlConn.Open()
            Dim Query As String
            Query = "insert into syscore.normaluser (nusername,nemail,npass,nphone,ncity) values ('" & TextBoxNUsern.Text & "','" & TextBoxNEmail.Text & "','" & TextBoxNPass.Text & "','" & TextBoxNPhone.Text & "','" & TextBoxNCity.Text & "')"
            MySqlCmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
            MySqlRea = MySqlCmd.ExecuteReader

            MessageBox.Show("Registration has been completed")
            MySqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MySqlConn.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

**OPTIONAL:** Ok. I have another question maybe you can solve at the same time. How could i add guid generator when the register submit button is pressed if you know what i mean? i have it in my website asp.net that i made myself. Would be very nice and helpful.

Big thanks for those who will try to help me. I will check this topic every 5 minutes.

Comment: My important question is the username validator the guid is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the important part. Optional is not needed for me but would've been good. Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovoVfHW3Q8Y.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding a uniqueidentifier column and adding the default to generate new guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974939/adding-a-uniqueidentifier-column-and-adding-the-default-to-generate-new-guid)

Downvotes probably because you didn't paste your code here, plus the fact that the question has been asked and answered many times. Did you search before asking?

Comment: Yes i did search and i tried to paste the code here but it didin't work it was in wrong lines and messed up.

Comment: Ok. Do you know how to validate the username?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189724/should-validation-of-unique-fields-be-handled-on-database-level that has also been asked and answered here.

Comment: I dont understand. I like when someone give me code example atleast to understand.