# Difference between unique and non-unique index in mysql in terms of performance/implementation

Tags: mysql, database

I have a simple INNODB mysql table sql_statements

```
id, text, sha1

id   - primary key
text - variable length strings.           
sha1 - SHA1 hash of the text
```

text column contains strings like sql query text like "select * from abc", "insert into ...", ...

I have a unique index on the sha1 column to make searching for sql_statements with a given text fast.

However, one limitation of the design is that we can not insert 2 rows with the same sha1 hash.

To get around this, I am considering making the index non-unique.

What is the difference between unique and non-unique indexes in mysql in terms of performance? Both are implemented as B-trees so my guess is performance should be similar.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql 5.0 indexes - Unique vs Non Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388982/mysql-5-0-indexes-unique-vs-non-unique)

Comment: It's still unclear for what this table is used for. You answered what is stored in but not why you store it. I'm afraid it's for some strange performance "optimizations".

Answer (score 4):

With a `unique` constraint the query plan can be optimized to stop on first match. So having a unique index might be faster.

If you're interested in equality queries on the statement-column, then I recommend to use a Hash-Index on that column and drop your own hash column.

In any case I would not use some unique constraint when the column is non-unique just for performance, because it's simply wrong. Furthermore I am curious of what your `sql_statements` table is used for.

Comment: I updated the question to indicate what the table is used for.

Comment: I would recommend to drop the hash column and using a non-unique index on the statement-column. It's the DBMS job to query this fast.