# Performance-issues with mysql + php

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I have the following PHP script, which executes a MySQL-Query.

```
$sSql = "SELECT DISTINCT t1.* "
      . "FROM import_data t1 "
      . "INNER JOIN import_profiles imp on t1.profile_id = imp.id "
      . "WHERE imp.creditornr = " . $vendor . " "
      . "AND t1.vendor = '" . $k . "' "
      . "AND t1.importRun = (SELECT MAX(importRun) AS importRun
         FROM import_data
         WHERE sku=t1.sku
           AND profile_id = t1.profile_id)";
```

In native SQL, a query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM import_data t1
INNER JOIN import_profiles imp on t1.profile_id = imp.id
WHERE imp.creditornr = 73329
AND t1.vendor = 'rackmountit'
AND t1.importRun = (SELECT MAX(importRun) AS importRun
            FROM import_data
            WHERE sku=t1.sku
              AND profile_id = t1.profile_id)
```

This is the explain of one of those queries: (I run > 10 of those) and the DB currently has ~100.000 entries (rising).

[image: Explain]

Also, those are the tables which are used in this statements:

**import_data**
[image: Table import_data]

**import_profiles**
[image: Table import_profiles]

I have no idea how, since I'm not that good in mysql, but are there any ideas how to increase the performance of those (sub)queries? Currently they are running > 1:00 and I need to optimize it.

Thanks and let me know, if you need further information.

**EDIT 1**
Added the CREATE TABLE statements

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET time_zone = '+00:00';

CREATE TABLE `import_data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `profile_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `evp` double NOT NULL,
  `ek` double NOT NULL,
  `articletext1` text NOT NULL,
  `articletext2` text NOT NULL,
  `ean` text NOT NULL,
  `stock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `zolltarif` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tstamp` date NOT NULL,
  `importRun` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE `import_profiles` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creditornr` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `structure` text NOT NULL,
  `updatetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Import-Profile für Vorlieferanten';
```

Comment: What is your table schema or did I miss it?  Going to temporary is exceedingly bad in most cases as MySQL is writing a temp file to disk and then scanning through that.

Comment: If your data is valuable, which it likely is, copy the table in question to a dev machine and try adding indexes to columns in your where conditions.  That vendor field is likely ideal if its cardinality is less then 50% ( super ideal if its below 20%).

Comment: You can [read this](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) and see if it guides you? Basically add indexes only on the columns referenced in the where clauses

Comment: @David you mean the structure of `import_data`? Using some kind of phpMyAdmin, since I don't have access to a shell. Also, how can I check the cardinalitiy?

Comment: Do you have any indexes in your tables? Could you publish import_data and import_profiles CREATE TABLE output here?

Comment: DasSaffe - Look at this to get an idea of which fields in your data can help you cut down on total rows selected - http://stackoverflow.com/a/1002363/9908   Smaller the count, the better.   "You cannot make a computer run faster, but you can make it do less."

Comment: @Taras I added the CREATE TABLE output

Comment: @DasSaffe Likely not an issue given what seems like a small amount of data but when the day comes when you deal with larger amounts of data.  This section of MySQL manual is your friend - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimizing-innodb.html

Comment: @DasSaffe Found a decent blog post talking about indexes and InnoDB ( table engine you're using ) - https://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-2-cardinality/      I have to run, but my parting advice.  DO NOT PUT INDEXES ON HIGH CARDINALITY COLUMNS... and use them as minimal as possible.  MySQL will try to keep indexes loaded in memory so less is crucial.   Too many and you hurt performance overall ( rapid loading/unloading).

Comment: Does anyone think that prepared statements **_might_** help??

Comment: @CayceK - Prepared statements won't help enough to notice.  The performance problem is the lack of indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add indexes for fields: import_data.profile_id, import_data.sku and import_profiles.creditornr it should increase your SQL queries speed

Comment: so, when I can choose what type of index, I choose "index" instead of "unique", unless I can guarantee that this field will be unique?

Comment: @DasSaffe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388982/mysql-5-0-indexes-unique-vs-non-unique   Now that you know what keywords to look for, stackoverflow is your best friend for answers.

Comment: @DasSaffe you should add primary keys. This makes them more unique. that is best done (most often) on the id.

Comment: @CayceK Been a while but I don't believe InnoDB allows for tables without a primary key, ideally one that is not a natural key.

Comment: @David now I'm out of my element. Didn't notice the InnoDB engine. That is a solid thing to know. Not sure if it forces a primary key / has one if you don't implicitly define one. I'm going to bow out of the conversation :D

Comment: @David, InnoDB can't work with tables without primary key defined. If some table does not have it is created automatically by InnoDB engine. Type of indexes should be selected according to your data in DB. Correct indexes will increase performance any way.

Comment: That indeed boosted the performance IMMENSE! The precedure went down from over 30 min to 5 sec (!)

Comment: @Taras I stopped using MySQL around 5.1-5.2 but wasn't sure if that had somehow changed in last few updates.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your schema and how your data actually looks like.

The vendor field seems like a good candidate for putting an index on it.  But that depends on how unique it is.  If every row of the vendor column is unique, then look for something else to filter on.

Using an analogy of shopping for groceries:
As I mentioned in the column, going to temporary is like having a very long grocery list, copying all or almost all of the entire list to a new sheet of paper, and THEN going through the copy to find which items in the list are appropriate to the grocery isle you are in.

Edit: SO answer for how to add indexes, recommend reading comments as well. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002635/9908

Answer (score 0):

```
import_data:  INDEX(sku, profile_id, importRun) -- for the MAX subquery
import_data:  INDEX(vendor)
import_profiles:  INDEX(creditornr, id)
```

(It is unclear which of the last two to have, but it won't hurt to include both.)

Since your query is somewhat a "groupwise max", see [*groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).