# Does MySQL maintain a time complexity of O(logn) when searching for a range of values?

Tags: mysql, time-complexity, comparison-operators

Let's say I have a database schema that looks like

`id | value`

Where value1 is NOT unique but id is. If I want to select all values in the range 5 < value < 10 so that my query would look like

`SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE value BETWEEN 5 AND 10`

does the database maintain a selection time complexity of O(logn)?

Comment: Yes, if `value` is indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Paul Spiegel and [this answer on SO that I missed during my search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/389824/4518057), the time complexity of O(logn) is maintained.